# Sorting Big Table

Tags: qt, sorting, qtableview

I'm using QTableView with reimplemented QAbstractTableModel and QSortFilterProxyModel.
In this tabel some file sizes were displayed.
 `data(...)` method for Size column return a long long value wich is formated in QStyleditemDelegate like 2,38 Gb
For exmple if in table 8000 items were populated sorting will took about 2-3 sec.
How can I improve this?
**edit1**

```
QVariant FileViewModel::data( const QModelIndex &index, int role /*= Qt::DisplayRole */ ) const
{
    qDebug() << "FileViewModel::data" << index.row() << index.column();
    int column = index.column();
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole && dataSource.storrage.is_valid())
    {
        int row = index.row();
        internal_file_entry file = dataSource.storrage.internal_at(row);
        switch (column)
        {
        case 0:
            return QString::fromStdString(dataSource.storrage.file_path(file));
        case 1:
            return dataSource.storrage.file_size(file); 
        case 2:
            return dataSource.progresses[row]*100.0f;
        case 3:
            return dataSource.priorities[row];
        }
    }
}
```

creating and applying model

```
void AppMainView::setupFileTabel()
{
    fileViewModel = new FileViewModel(this);
    QSortFilterProxyModel* proxymodel = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
    proxymodel->setSourceModel(fileViewModel);
    fileTableView->setModel(proxymodel);
    fileTableView->setShowGrid(false);
    fileTableView->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
    fileTableView->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
    fileTableView->setItemDelegateForColumn(1,new FileSizeItemDelegate(this));
    fileTableView->setItemDelegateForColumn(2,new ProgressItemDelegate(this));
    fileTableView->setItemDelegateForColumn(3,new PriorityItemDelegate(this));
    fileTableView->setSortingEnabled(true);
    fileTableView->setColumnWidth(0,300);
    fileTableView->setColumnWidth(1,65);
    fileTableView->setColumnWidth(2,65);
    fileTableView->setColumnWidth(3,70);
    setupFileTabelContextMenu();
}
```

Comment: Quite difficult diagnosis unless you attach the code. My gut instinct is that you are auto-resizing the columns?

Comment: here is some code from model and some of  applying changes to view